# What exactly is the difference between Box::into_raw() and Box::leak()?

Tags: rust

As you know, both Box::into_raw() and Box::leak() consume the current Box and lose ownership of the memory.

The two just seem to have different types of return values, what exactly is the other difference between them?

How about typical application scenarios?

Comment: `into_raw` is typically used for FFI to get a pointer that can be sent to the other language, and is usually matched with a later call to `from_raw` to reclaim ownership and free the memory. `leak` is typically used to get a `'static` reference to satisfy some API requirement and is usually kept until the program exits.

Comment: @Jmb: Can you post that as an answer? Seems to me that that pretty much covers it, except for maybe some emphasis that getting a `'static` reference in safe code is a strong commitment that that lifetime is actually true.

Comment: More information can be found [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/can-box-leak-be-complemented-with-box-from-raw/64478).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw) is typically used for FFI to get a pointer that can be sent to the other language, and is usually matched with a later call to [`from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) to reclaim ownership and free the memory.

[`leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) is typically used to get a `'static` reference to satisfy some API requirement and is usually kept until the program exits.